# Control the height of dendrograms python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How do I modify the height of the dendrograms that `scipy` calculates during hierarchical clustering?

**MWE**

```
 import scipy
 import pylab
 import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

 # Generate random features and distance matrix.
 x = scipy.rand(40)
 D = scipy.zeros([40,40])
 for i in range(40):
      for j in range(40):
         D[i,j] = abs(x[i] - x[j])

 # Compute and plot first dendrogram.
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09,0.1,0.2,0.6])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='centroid')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# Compute and plot second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.71,0.6,0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='single')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# Plot distance matrix.
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.1,0.6,0.6])
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = D[idx1,:]
D = D[:,idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=pylab.cm.YlGnBu)
axmatrix.set_xticks([])
axmatrix.set_yticks([])

# Plot colorbar.
axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.91,0.1,0.02,0.6])
pylab.colorbar(im, cax=axcolor)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply an axis to the dendrograms, and then treat them like any other plot. At the moment, it looks as if you've made the axis, but not added it to the dendrogram.  What happens if you use

```
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right', ax=ax1)
```

etc. in your calls?